# SQL report builder 3.0 - display of results via Tablix

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am new to SQL and currently experimenting with using Report Builder 3.0. I have a basic report which i need some help with, i hope the answer is also straightforward, this sitaution is as follows;

My report contains a Header tablix and a detail Tablix sitting underneath it, these are both populated through 2 seperate queries from the same datasource

When i run the report what is happening is all the data from relating to the header is filled first then the detail is filled after, I have tried to show this below;

Header detail for team 1
Header detail for team 2
Header detail for team 3 etc...

Detail for team 1
Detail for team 2
Detail for team 3 etc...

**What i actually want is**

header detail for team 1
detail for team 1

header detail for team 2
detail for team 2

and so on, i had an idea whilst driving home from work that i should just combine the datasets into one Tablix but thats not possible when i have tried this just now.

Any ideas how i can resolve this?

This is my first report in report builder and so on a steep learning curve!

Cheers